# Convert date into dd-mm

Tags: android, json, date

I have a date coming in this format("2014-04-09 00:00:00") from json, but in the application i only want to show in this format ("09-April").How can i achieve this.
Please help me.

JSON STRING

```
{
    "NewDataSet": {
        "Table": [
            {
                "Action_Flag": "1",
                "Address": "Sant Vihar, eastern Highhway.",
                "Batch_ID": "33",
                "City": "Gurgaon",
                "Company_Code": "1",
                "Country_Code": "US",
                "Event_ID": "E041402",
                "Event_Name": "Citi Finance",
                "Event_Venue": "kamani",
                "IEvent_Code": "1960",
                "IEvent_Status_Code": "3",
                "Is_Synced": "0",
                "ISponsor_Code": "12",
                "Setup_Date_Time": "2014-04-04 10:00:00",
                "Sponsor_Name": "CitiFinancial",
                "State_Code": "IN",
                "TearDownDateTime": "2014-04-08 21:00:00",
                "TearDownDateTime_Val": "2014-04-08 10:0"
            },
            {
                "Action_Flag": "1",
                "Address": "Vihar Complex, lal Dongarwadi",
                "Batch_ID": "33",
                "City": "Mumbai",
                "Company_Code": "1",
                "Country_Code": "CAN",
                "Event_ID": "E041406",
                "Event_Name": "City",
                "Event_Venue": "bbb",
                "IEvent_Code": "1964",
                "IEvent_Status_Code": "3",
                "Is_Synced": "0",
                "ISponsor_Code": "12",
                "Setup_Date_Time": "2014-04-09 10:00:00",
                "Sponsor_Name": "CitiFinancial",
                "State_Code": "AB",
                "TearDownDateTime": "2014-04-10 11:00:00",
                "TearDownDateTime_Val": "2014-04-10 -1:0"
            },
            {
                "Action_Flag": "1",
                "Address": "Madhuban Colony,Eastern Highwa",
                "Batch_ID": "33",
                "City": "mumbai",
                "Company_Code": "1",
                "Country_Code": "CAN",
                "Event_ID": "E041407",
                "Event_Name": "Roushh",
                "Event_Venue": "Sultan nagar",
                "IEvent_Code": "1965",
                "IEvent_Status_Code": "3",
                "Is_Synced": "0",
                "ISponsor_Code": "10",
                "Setup_Date_Time": "2014-04-09 00:00:00",
                "Sponsor_Name": "Roush Fenway Racing",
                "State_Code": "AB",
                "TearDownDateTime": "2014-04-10 22:00:00",
                "TearDownDateTime_Val": "2014-04-10 10:0"
            },
            {
                "Action_Flag": "1",
                "Address": "Shewan, Holden Nagar.",
                "Batch_ID": "33",
                "City": "Alwatwa",
                "Company_Code": "1",
                "Country_Code": "CAN",
                "Event_ID": "E041408",
                "Event_Name": "SPC",
                "Event_Venue": "Unit-122",
                "IEvent_Code": "1966",
                "IEvent_Status_Code": "3",
                "Is_Synced": "0",
                "ISponsor_Code": "1",
                "Setup_Date_Time": "2014-04-11 10:00:00",
                "Sponsor_Name": "Aflac",
                "State_Code": "MB",
                "TearDownDateTime": "2014-04-11 20:00:00",
                "TearDownDateTime_Val": "2014-04-11 9:0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have a date coming in this format("2014-04-09 00:00:00") from json, but in the application i only want to show in this format ("09-apr").How can i achieve this.
Please help me.

Comment: what you have tried ?? and just use SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this below example.

```
    String myFormat1 = "dd-MMMM:"; // In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);


            text_time.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
```

From developer [SimpleDateFormate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
month in year   (Text)  M:1 MM:01 MMM:Jan MMMM:January MMMMM:J
```

so use forth one `MMMM:January`

Comment: i did like this
String format = "dd-MMM";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
tvStartDate.setText(sdf.format(event.startDate + "\n"));

Answer (score 1):

Use class [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). This might help you. Try to use pattern `dd-MMM`.

```
 String format = "dd-MMM";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
 sdf.format(your_date_object_from_JSON);
```

Comment: pls can u give me an example

Comment: Whether I answered on your question thanks in advance for accepting it.